# AngularJs table in double ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to visualize an json-object in  a table like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <tr ng-repeat="i in item">
    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
    <td>{{i.ip}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

If I do that I will see only a white screen.

This way works, but I need the data in an table.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <ul ng-repeat="i in item">
    <div>
      {{ i.id }}
      {{ i.ip }}
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Do you know a possible solution with a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 <table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in data">
  <tr ng-repeat="i in item">
    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
    <td>{{i.ip}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: look at my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake! The first ng-repeat must be in the table statement.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td >ip</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody ng-repeat="item in data">
                <tr ng-repeat="i in item">
                    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.ip}}</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```